# How to dynamic column mapping in ssis

Tags: ssis

I have large amount of flat files to migrate to sql server.Each file has different column length based on the metadata defined.Please tell me how i can create a single package to migrate all the files?

Answer (score -1):

If this is a one-time import, you can let the import/export wizard create the package for you.

If you need a more lasting solution, you can use BiML which dynamically creates packages at execution time based on available metadata.